# Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel Import converts special Characters into number 0

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a CSV file with some rows that has text/words that contain a special character like **ñ,**

What happened is that when I tried to import the CSV file, the words with characters above or alike will be converted to **0.**

I am using the **ToModel**

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
```

To reproduce this, just try to put a special character in one of the cells of your CSV file, then import it like:

```
Excel::import(new CsvImport, request()->file('file'));
```

> Output : *The resulting inserted data that has a special character will be stored as 0*

Note: Adding data directly from the *Form* does not convert the special characters to 0, only when uploading CSV through import

Comment: make your Collation as `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @DilipHirapara it's already set like that

Comment: And what's your question? Does https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/431 help?

Comment: I checked the link but the solution provided doesn't seem to work , also I'm using import not the load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your config set the 'use_bom' to 'true'

```
    'csv'                    => [
        'delimiter'              => ',',
        'enclosure'              => '"',
        'line_ending'            => PHP_EOL,
        'use_bom'                => true,
        'include_separator_line' => false,
        'excel_compatibility'    => false,
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
$data = Excel::load('file.csv', false, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Or in the file configuration of excel config/excel.php

```
      'csv'                    => [
        'delimiter'              => ';',
        'input_encoding'         => 'ISO-8859-1',
        'enclosure'              => '"',
        'line_ending'            => PHP_EOL,
        'use_bom'                => false,
        'include_separator_line' => false,
        'excel_compatibility'    => true,
    ],
```